# Realm - Delete objects from realm in migration block

Tags: swift, realm

I need to delete objects from a realm during a migration.

I have an AccountManager which contains :

```
func logOut() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(realm.objects(Account.self))
        realm.delete(realm.objects(Address.self))
        ... // Other deletions
    }
}
```

But whenever I use the logOut() function in a migration block it just fails.

```
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 11,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 11) {
                // Delete objects from realm
                AccountManager().logOut() // DOESN'T WORK
            }
    })

    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

I absolutely need users to relog after this update - Is there any way I could perform these deletions in a migration block ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can tell Realm to delete when migration needed.

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 10,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in


    },
    deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true
)
```

Comment: Is there any way I could specify this realm deletion only has to be applied  when migrating from version 10 to 11 ?

Comment: I never try that, I guess you have to write your own migration code. Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40467810/2003085

Comment: for deleting realm only when migrating from certain versions, check out https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/502#issuecomment-228058951

Answer (score 18):

You can use `Migration.deleteData(forType typeName: String)` instead `Realm.delete(_:)` as follows.

```
Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 11, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
    if oldSchemaVersion < 11
        migration.deleteData(forType: Account.className)
        migration.deleteData(forType: Address.className)
        ...
```

Comment: Hi , please check my question about realm migration , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855380/how-can-i-replace-a-listobjects-with-object-field-in-realm